# Why hydrofluoric acid (HF) has two Raman bands?

Tags: raman

Hydrofluoric acid ($\ce{HF}$) is a diatomic molecule with only one vibrational coordinate. Therefore I would expect only one Raman band, however there are two. Why?

[image][image]([source](http://www.process-instruments-inc.com/pages/acid.html))

Comment: How is it even possible that HF is vibrating at 600 wavenumbers? It's gas phase vibrational mode is up around 4400? I wonder if these are the modes of vibration between HF-HF dimer (the higher one) and HF-H2O dimer. I just imagine those would be lower frequency. Also, both peaks, particularly an HF-HF dimer should increase when HF is added which is what the percentages are I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I've been doing some digging and I think I have a possible answer so I'm gonna post it and if I'm misinterpreting information, I'm open to being told so!

As I said in my comment, this vibration has to be coming from some dimer which is formed because if one of these modes were the $\ce{HF}$ fundamental it would be up around $4000\ cm^{-1}$.

So, I found [this paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/79/8/10.1063/1.446286) which uses FTIR to analyze $\ce{H2O/HF}$ complexes. They find two librational modes (which I believe is just a solvated rotational/rocking mode basically) which they identify as coming from the $\ce{H2O--HF}$ dimer. They assign these two frequencies at $635.5\ cm^{-1}$ and $753.1\ cm^{-1}$. Those two values are extremely similar to the frequencies we're seeing in the spectra you posted which is why I think we might be on to something here. Unfortunately I don't have access to the paper so I can't go into any more detail really.

In answer to your question of how we could even be seeing multiple peaks in an $\ce{HF}$ spectrum, the answer is that we're not looking at just $\ce{HF}$ here!

We know that both $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{HF}$ are very strong hydrogen bonding molecules, so it's no surprise that we find peaks which are associated with the various vibrational modes of the dimers present. And, once we have a dimer, we expect to find all sorts of rotational and vibrational modes.

So, to conclude, I'm fairly certain that the modes we're seeing in this spectra are two (and I think the only two because my digging around says this dimer has $C_s$ symmetry) librational modes of the $\ce{H2O--HF}$ dimer, each rotating about a different axis of the water.

---

Source:

**Andrews, L., & Johnson, G. L. (1983). FTIR spectra of water–hydrogen fluoride complexes in solid argon. Evidence for inversion doubling in the HF librational modes of H2O––HF. The Journal of chemical physics, 79(8), 3670-3677.**

Comment: (1) aren't IR and Raman wavenumbers of the same vibration supposed to be quite different (while you say that the IR wavenumbers are very similar to the Raman ones in the charts). (2) both IR and Raman originate in intramolecular transitions so how can an intermolecular interaction be expressed in the spectra?

Comment: Not necessarily. The paper I cite has the water and HF in a solution of really really cold Argon so we could expect that the vibrations will be something like a regular solution. The only thing that makes IR and Raman quite different is that certain modes are active for one and not active for the other and Raman is usually in solution. Being in a liquid generally changes the frequency of vibrations. Also, you can think of a dimer as being a new molecule that's just held together by a weak bond. Then it's no surprise to see new Vibrational modes show up.

Comment: Also, to convince yourself that Raman can resemble IR, by simply looking at the frequency which is identified as coming from water, we can see that this is water's bending mode but is shifted down about 200 wavenumbers due to hydrogen bonding and is also wider because there are many waters in varying hydrogen bound geometries. This same shift does not apply to the HF/H2O dimer because it only exists when there's hydrogen bonding anyways! There might be slight shifts associated with a third water complexing in, but this is probably a small effect.